# Java SWT: How to set the window to be resizable \ not resizable on the fly?

Tags: java, shell, resize, window, swt

After a lot of search and research, I couldn't find any answer.
I will very appreciate the person that could help me.

In SWT java,
I want my window to be not resizable, so I define it like this:

```
shell = new Shell(SWT.CLOSE | SWT.TITLE | SWT.MIN);
```

But then I want to change it to be resizable (for example after I click a button).
How can I change the style of the shell on the fly?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't change the style of a `Shell` after creation. Unfortunately, I'm not able to provide an alternative. Looking forward to answers to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the style of a `Shell` once it has been created so you can't do this directly.

What you can do is create a new `Shell` (and all its contents) with the desired style and set its bounds to be the same as the old `Shell` and then close the old shell. Eclipse does this when it wants to convert a tool tip window in to a normal window.

Comment: OK, thanks, I tried it and managed to get something close to what I wanted.
But I don't like the effect of it - it seems like a window is closed and another one is opened.
Moreover, I need to assign all the widgets again to the new shell.
Good to know this option exists, but I rather prefer to limit the resizability manually (by capturing events of window control and resize the window to the default dimensions).
Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: Specifying `SWT.ON_TOP` for the new shell helps make the change more seamless, but yes it is messy if there are a lot of controls.

Answer (score 1):

If you develop exclusively for windows, you can achieve this with non pure SWT code (non portable). There are no visible glitches, no problems with re-parenting controls (see [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=272007), for example). Only the resizable property is changed. Here is the snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);

    final int style = OS.GetWindowLong(shell.handle, OS.GWL_STYLE);
    OS.SetWindowLong(shell.handle, OS.GWL_STYLE, style & ~0x00040000);

    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

### [WS_SIZEBOX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) = 0x00040000L

Edit: 
simple functions to use:

```
private static final int WS_SIZEBOX = 0x00040000;

public static void setResizable(Shell shell, boolean resizable) {
    final int style = OS.GetWindowLong(shell.handle, OS.GWL_STYLE);
    final int newStyle = resizable ? style | WS_SIZEBOX : style & ~WS_SIZEBOX;
    OS.SetWindowLong(shell.handle, OS.GWL_STYLE, newStyle);
}

public static boolean isResizable(Shell shell) {
    final int style = OS.GetWindowLong(shell.handle, OS.GWL_STYLE);
    return (style & WS_SIZEBOX) != 0;
}
```