# Java (Eclipse) WindowBuilder setting maximum dimensions

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, fixed, dimensions

I have built a window application using the SWT WindowBuilder in Eclipse. I want the window to be a set size whilst the application is running.

This means that I do not want the user to be able to resize the window e.g. disable window resizing and if that is not possible then I would like to ensure that the window has a maximum size (this is called bounds in Eclipse).

Looking at the official documentation I cannot find a setMaximumSize. Only a setMinimumSize (which I have already specified).

[Official documentation link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setMinimumSize%28java.awt.Dimension%29)

Is there a way of getting the size of the window if it changes (such as an event handler). If there is how would I use an event handler to monitor size and change the size back to 300,600 if it were to change?

I only want the window size to be 300 width and 600 height. IS THAT TOO MUCH TO ASK!? :'(

How could I go about setting an infinite loop to constantly set the dimensions? What would the impact of this be on the performance of the application?

Comment: Don't include the SWT.RESIZE style in the window style and it won't be resizable.

Comment: @greg-449 I have looked around for SWT.RESIZE and I am unable to find it in my project.

Comment: Do you create a Shell? Perhaps it's being created on your behalf by some code you're calling. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875083/java-swt-how-to-set-the-window-to-be-resizable-not-resizable-on-the-fly

Comment: @DavidConrad Yes, I have created a Shell. And as I understand it, the display cannot be changed once created. I see.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can we auto resize the size of components in SWT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928741/how-can-we-auto-resize-the-size-of-components-in-swt)